# How can I get cloth sewing to properly connect seams?

Tags: cloth-simulation

I'm attempting to sew together a simple, low poly shirt onto an equally simply and low poly character. However, no matter what I do, I absolutely cannot get any of the seams to stitch together properly. This happens regardless of how much cloth I allot, the cloth's physical properties, the simulation quality, the sewing force, the shrinking factor, and even self collisions. I've tried subdividing the cloth more and adding loop cuts in various places to no avail, and similarly replacing the crappy humanoid model that I threw together with a proper makehumans model doesn't seem to change anything.

[image: gap]

What am I missing here?

Blend file: https://pasteall.org/blend/62d27a1e85284fcbbb399520e1c27b87